# Translating between cartesian and screen coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, coordinates, coordinate-systems

For my game I need functions to translate between two coordinate systems. Well it's mainly math question but what I need is the C++ code to do it and a bit of explanation how to solve my issue.

Screen coordiantes:

a) top left corner is 0,0

b) no minus values

c) right += x (the more is x value, the more on the right is point)

d) bottom +=y

Cartesian 2D coordinates:

a) middle point is (0, 0)

b) minus values do exist

c) right += x

d) bottom -= y (the less is y, the more at the bottom is point)

I need an easy way to translate from one system to another and vice versa. To do that, (I think) I need some knowledge like where is the (0, 0) [top left corner in screen coordinates] placed in the cartesian coordinates.

However there is a problem that for some point in cartesian coordinates after translating it to screen ones, the position in screen coordinates may be minus, which is a nonsense. I cant put top left corner of screen coordinates in (-inifity, +infinity) cartesian coords...

How can I solve this? The only solution I can think of is to place screen (0, 0) in cartesian (0, 0) and only use IV quarter of cartesian system, but in that case using cartesian system is pointless...

I'm sure there are ways for translating screen coordinates into cartesian coordinates and vice versa, but I'm doing something wrong in my thinking with that minus values.

Comment: the screen coordinate **is** cartesian?  when did it become non-cartesian?

Comment: he wants to have negative coordinates

Comment: @thang the Y axis is different in screen and cartesian.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but I thought Cartesian just means it's R^2 with L2 metric (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).  You can flip it anyway you want so long as the flipping/transformation is an isometry.

Comment: @thang well you are right, but I think the question is understable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The basic algorithm to translate from cartesian coordinates to screen coordinates are

```
screenX = cartX + screen_width/2
screenY = screen_height/2 - cartY
```

But as you mentioned, cartesian space is infinite, and your screen space is not.  This can be solved easily by changing the resolution between screen space and cartesian space.  The above algorithm makes 1 unit in cartesian space = 1 unit/pixel in screen space.  If you allow for other ratios, you can "zoom" out or in your screen space to cover all of the cartesian space necessary.

This would change the above algorithm to

```
screenX = zoom_factor*cartX + screen_width/2
screenY = screen_height/2 - zoom_factor*cartY
```

Now you handle negative (or overly large) screenX and screenY by modifying your zoom factor until all your cartesian coordinates will fit on the screen.

You could also allow for panning of the coordinate space too, meaning, allowing the center of cartesian space to be off-center of the screen.  This could also help in allowing your zoom_factor to stay as tight as possible but also fit data which isn't evenly distributed around the origin of cartesian space.

This would change the algorithm to

```
screenX = zoom_factor*cartX + screen_width/2 + offsetX
screenY = screen_height/2 - zoom_factor*cartY + offsetY
```

Answer (score 7):

You must know the size of the screen in order to be able to convert

Convert to Cartesian:

```
cartesianx = screenx - screenwidth / 2;
cartesiany = -screeny + screenheight / 2;
```

Convert to Screen:

```
screenx = cartesianx + screenwidth / 2;
screeny = -cartesiany + screenheight / 2;
```

For cases where you have a negative screen value:
I would not worry about this, this content will simply be clipped so the user will not see. If this *is* a problem, I would add some constraints that prevent the cartesian coordinate from being too large. Another solution, since you can't have the edges be +/- infinity, would be to scale your coordinates (e.g. 1 pixel = 10 cartesian) Let's call this `scalefactor`. The equations are now:

Convert to Cartesian with scale factor:

```
cartesianx = scalefactor*screenx - screenwidth / 2;
cartesiany = -scalefactor*screeny + screenheight / 2;
```

Convert to Screen with scale factor:

```
screenx = (cartesianx + screenwidth / 2) / scalefactor;
screeny = (-cartesiany + screenheight / 2) / scalefactor;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to know the width and height of the screen.

Then you can do:

```
cartX =   screenX - (width / 2);
cartY = -(screenY - (height / 2));
```

And:

```
screenX =  cartX + (width / 2);
screenY = -cartY + (height / 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will always have the problem that the result could be off the screen -- either as a negative value, or as a value larger than the available screen size.

Sometimes that won't matter:  e.g., if your graphical API accepts negative values and clips your drawing for you.  Sometimes it will matter, and for those cases you should have a function that checks if a set of screen coordinates is on the screen.

You could also write your own clipping functions that try to do something reasonable with coordinates that fall off the screen (such as truncating negative screen coordinates to 0, and coordinates that are too large to the maximum onscreen coordinate).  However, keep in mind that "reasonable" depends on what you're trying to do, so it might be best to hold off on defining such functions until you actually need them.

---

In any case, as other answers have noted, you can convert between the coordinate systems as:

```
cart.x = screen.x - width/2;
cart.y = height/2 - screen.y;
```

and

```
screen.x = cart.x + width/2;
screen.y = height/2 - cart.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got some boost c++ for you, based on microsoft article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635757(v=vs.85).aspx

You just need to know two screen points and two points in your coordinate system. Then you can convert point from one system to another.

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector_proxy.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/triangular.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/lu.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

 /* Matrix inversion routine.
 Uses lu_factorize and lu_substitute in uBLAS to invert a matrix */
template<class T>
bool InvertMatrix(const boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T>& input, boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T>& inverse)
{
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::permutation_matrix<std::size_t> pmatrix;

    // create a working copy of the input
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T> A(input);

    // create a permutation matrix for the LU-factorization
    pmatrix pm(A.size1());

    // perform LU-factorization
    int res = lu_factorize(A, pm);
    if (res != 0)
        return false;

    // create identity matrix of "inverse"
    inverse.assign(boost::numeric::ublas::identity_matrix<T> (A.size1()));

    // backsubstitute to get the inverse
    lu_substitute(A, pm, inverse);

    return true;
}

PointF ConvertCoordinates(PointF pt_in,
    PointF pt1, PointF pt2, PointF pt1_, PointF pt2_)
{

    float matrix1[]={
         pt1.X,           pt1.Y,           1.0f,           0.0f,
        -pt1.Y,           pt1.X,           0.0f,           1.0f,
         pt2.X,           pt2.Y,           1.0f,           0.0f,
        -pt2.Y,           pt2.X,           0.0f,           1.0f
    };

    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<float> M(4, 4);
    CopyMemory(&M.data()[0], matrix1, sizeof(matrix1));

    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<float> M_1(4, 4);
    InvertMatrix<float>(M, M_1);

    double vector[] = {
        pt1_.X,
        pt1_.Y,
        pt2_.X,
        pt2_.Y
    };

    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<float> u(4);
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<float> u1(4);
    u(0) = pt1_.X;
    u(1) = pt1_.Y;
    u(2) = pt2_.X;
    u(3) = pt2_.Y;

    u1 = boost::numeric::ublas::prod(M_1, u);

    PointF pt;
    pt.X = u1(0)*pt_in.X + u1(1)*pt_in.Y + u1(2);
    pt.Y = u1(1)*pt_in.X - u1(0)*pt_in.Y + u1(3);
    return pt;
}
```