# How to convert cartesian coordinates to computer screen coordinates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, cartesian-coordinates

I want to convert cartesian coordinates to computer screen coordinates. Is there any generic algorithm to do this which could handle all test cases.
[image][image]

Comment: add/subtract/multiply/divide ... no need for anything more complex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880601/translating-between-cartesian-and-screen-coordinates might help you

Comment: Are you referencing viewport or `window.outerWidth`, `window.innerWidth`? What issue are you having?

Comment: @VinodLouis— [*Translating between cartesian and screen coordinates*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880601/translating-between-cartesian-and-screen-coordinates) will do me for a duplicate.