# Convert xy coordinates (in pixels) to barycentric coordinates (x,y,z)

Tags: math, equation

This may be a strange one but I have a graphic of a triangle like this:
[image: triangle]

and in a survey platform, whenever one click on a point in this graphic an x,y coordinates in **pixels** are recorded like this (the origin for x,y is from the top-left of the image)

Note: the clicking is only allowed inside the green triangle.

[image: coordinates]

Is there a way to convert these coordinates to barycentric coordinates (x,y,z) with respect to a simplex in 2D (this triangle)?

If so what is the appropriate equation given that we have the x,y in **pixels**.

Would it matter if they are in pixels or are they still considered Cartesian coordinates?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, pixels are Cartesian coordinates, so apply usual [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: Okay thanks! What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880601/translating-between-cartesian-and-screen-coordinates
Is it only to get negative and positive values?
`cartesianx = screenx - screenwidth / 2;
cartesiany = -screeny + screenheight / 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you know the coordinates of the three vertex of the triangle

```
A: {ax, ay}
B: {bx, by}
C: {cx, cy}
```

and you want to take an arbitrary point

```
P: {px, py}
```

and find the three barycentric coordinates `w_A`, `w_B`, `w_C` such that

```
px = w_A * ax + w_B * bx + w_C * cx
py = w_A * ay + w_B * by + w_C * cy
1  = w_A + w_B + w_C
```

Turn this into a linear algebra problem

```
| px |   | ax  bx  cx | | w_A |
| py | = | ay  by  cy | | w_B |
|  1 |   |  1   1   1 | | w_C |
```

to be solved for `{w_A,w_B,w_C}`

Use the sample code below which I tested with the following results

```
Triangle A: <5, 0>
Triangle B: <2.5, 5>
Triangle C: <0, 0>
Random Point: <3.169941, 0.417091>
Barycentric: (0.5922791,0.08341819,0.3243028)
Target Point: <3.169941, 0.417091>
```

#### Triangle.cs

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Triangle
    {
        public Triangle(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
        }

        public Vector2 A { get; set; }
        public Vector2 B { get; set; }
        public Vector2 C { get; set; }

        public Vector2 GetPoint(float w_A, float w_B, float w_C) => GetPoint((w_A, w_B, w_C));
        public Vector2 GetPoint((float w_A, float w_B, float w_C) coord)
        {
            return coord.w_A * A + coord.w_B * B + coord.w_C * C;
        }
        public (float w_A, float w_B, float w_C) GetBarycentric(Vector2 P)
        {
            float D = A.X * (B.Y - C.X) + A.Y * (B.X - C.X) + B.X * C.Y - B.Y * C.X;

            float w_A = ((B.Y - C.Y) * P.X + (C.X - B.X) * P.Y + (B.X * C.Y - B.Y * C.X)) / D;
            float w_B = ((C.Y - A.Y) * P.X + (A.X - C.X) * P.Y + (C.X * A.Y - C.Y * A.X)) / D;
            float w_C = ((A.Y - B.Y) * P.X + (B.X - A.X) * P.Y + (A.X * B.Y - A.Y * B.X)) / D;

            return (w_A, w_B, w_C);
        }

        public bool Contains(Vector2 point)
        {
            var (w_A, w_B, w_C) = GetBarycentric(point);
            return w_A>=0 && w_A<=1
                && w_B>=0 && w_B<=1
                && w_C>=0 && w_C<=1;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    public static class Program
    {
        static readonly Random rng = new Random();

        static Vector2 RandomVector(float minValue = 0, float maxValue = 1)
        {
            return new Vector2(
                minValue + (maxValue - minValue) * (float)rng.NextDouble(),
                minValue + (maxValue - minValue) * (float)rng.NextDouble());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector2 A = new Vector2(5f,0f);
            Vector2 B = new Vector2(2.5f,5f);
            Vector2 C = new Vector2(0f,0f);

            var triangle = new Triangle(A, B, C);

            Console.WriteLine($"Triangle A: {A}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Triangle B: {B}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Triangle C: {C}");

            Vector2 P = RandomVector(0f, 5f);

            Console.WriteLine($"Random Point: {P}");

            var (w_A, w_B, w_C) = triangle.GetBarycentric(P);
            Console.WriteLine($"Barycentric: ({w_A},{w_B},{w_C})");

            Vector2 T = triangle.GetPoint(w_A, w_B, w_C);
            Console.WriteLine($"Target Point: {T}");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pixels are just the specific unit, this triangle representation would still be in cartesian coordinates, so you just apply the same formula, i.e. (as specified in the comments )[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: Okay thanks! I read this somewhere else so I got a little confused on the difference between pixels and cartesian coordinates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880601/translating-between-cartesian-and-screen-coordinates
`cartesianx = screenx - screenwidth / 2;
cartesiany = -screeny + screenheight / 2;`